# Child of a absolutely positioned item ignores bottom padding in firefox

Tags: css

I am trying to have an overlay using absolute positioning by setting all the four sides to have some value(top, right, bottom, left). This absolutely positioned element has a child element in it which is having a height and overflow auto. This element also has padding in all the sides. But unfortunately ignores the padding at the bottom.

This is happening only with the firefox browser. Chrome behaves fine. Does anyone know a way to have this fixed?

Here is the code

```css
 body {
   background: lightblue;
 }
 .abs {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   position: absolute;
   top: 20%;
   bottom: 20%;
   right: 30%;
   left: 30%;
   padding: 40px;
   overflow: auto;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="abs">
    <div>
      asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf
      asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf
      asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf
      asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf
      asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf
      asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf
      asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
      asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf
      asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf
      safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas df
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you tryed this.. padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;

Comment: I don't see any difference between Firefox and Chrome (the latest versions). If you scroll down the container, you'll see the bottom padding. But if you want to reduce the visible area of scrolling section, you'd better to use `border: 40px solid transparent;` instead of `padding`.

Comment: +1. @HashemQolami On Firefox 35.0.1 I can see the problem. I'm now updating to the last Firefox, I'll retry in 1 minute

Comment: The bug is still there in the last version, 36.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply the padding to the inner `<div>` instaed of your `.abs` that should apply the padding to the bottom of that text.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. But I have come up with another solution by adding a "." content to the after pseudo of .abs element. Quite near to the solution given by Steven.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like it might be a bug of scoller and padding system on Firefox. Which cause by the limitaion of scrolling of `child div` inside the `.abs`.

So far I come up with an solution to work around with it.

```css
body{
  background: lightblue;
}
.abs{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
  right: 30%;
  left: 30%;
  padding: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.abs div{
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="abs">
  <div>
    asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf as safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas dfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asfadf asdfsadfsadf safdasdfasfdas df
  </div>
</div>
```

Overide the `padding-bottom` on `.abs`. We will set it later on child div.

This will prevent chrome to double render the padding of 2 elements

***Edit*** remove the comments from CSS. It messed with the output of snippet. That mean, it wasn't work before this edit.